# c++ regexp allowing digits separated by dot

Tags: c++, regex

i need rexexp allowing up to two digits in a row separated by dots, like 1.2 or 1.2.3 or 1.2.3.45 etc., but not 1234 or 1.234 etc. I'm trying this "^[\d{1,2}.]+", but it allows all numbers. What's wrong?

Comment: Because its in a [class] `{1,2}` would be interpreted as a 5 character list not a quantifier.

Comment: Do you want to also match `12` or `1`?

Comment: The `.` in your regex `[class]` allows any character, so it's matching everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this:

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})+$
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGkOO4/2/)

Explanation:

1. `^` start of a string
2. `\d{1,2}` followed by one or two digits
3. `(` start of capture group
4. `\.\d{1,2}` followed by a dot and one or two digits
5. `)` end of capture group
6. `+` indicates the previous capture group be repeated 1 or more times
7. `$` end of string

Sample C++ Source ([run here](http://ideone.com/cp5676)):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string regx = R"(^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})+$)";
    string input = "1.2.346";
    smatch matches;
            if (regex_search(input, matches, regex(regx)))
            {
                cout<<"match found";
            }
            else
                cout<<"No match found";
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Strange, looks nice but output is nothing... May i use it wrong way?
create
`regex e("^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})+$");`
use
`if (!regex_search(t.substr(0, 10), e))`

There IS such sequence in the begining of _t_, and output IS NOT empty with my variant.

t looks like _1.2.10 Some text_ or just _lots of text_

Comment: @Stupid_Hedgehog, you may want to edit your question to include a code snippet, and the test inputs you're using to help other folks understand what you're trying to do. See [mcve]. It looks like Rizwan's solution should work, based on your description in the question, and people are upvoting it accordingly.

Comment: @Stupid_Hedgehog I have added a working sample source... you can try this

Comment: Problem solved, @Rizwan M.Tuman, very grateful to you. It was about _t.substr(0, 10)_, where i'm looking for matches, isn't ending by digit or dot, but some text, so _$_ isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last should not have more than 2 digits.

```
(\d{1,2}\.)+\d{1,2}(?=\b)
```

Comment: What if the last digit is at the end of the string?

Comment: This can be empty: `(\d{1,2}\.)+` 
The last digit is captured by this part: `\d{1,2}(?=\s)`

Comment: No, `(\d{1,2}\.)+` can't be empty (`+` = at least one), and there is no space when the string ends with a digit, so `\d{1,2}(?=\s)` will fail: https://regex101.com/r/RixAzd/1

Comment: This doesn't match anything. May i use it wrong way? create `regex e("^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})+$");` use `if (!regex_search(t.substr(0, 10), e))` There IS such sequence in the begining of _t_, and output IS NOT empty with my variant. t looks like _1.2.10 Some text_ or just _lots of text_

Comment: Really. It works only if the data contains at least two columns.
Is it possible that we have only one column? @Stupid_Hedgehog